# Cats: Implementing Contravariant for Predicates without a type alias?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor, scala-cats, type-level-computation

Say that a Predicate is a function A => Boolean, I want to implement an instance of Cats's "Contravariant Functor" type class for predicates.
I've also got an implicit class PredicateOps that defines union and intersect operators for predicates.

I have been able to get the instance to work using a type alias:

```
type Predicate[A] = A => Boolean

implicit val predicateContra = new Contravariant[Predicate] {
  override def contramap[A, B](fa: Predicate[A])(f: B => A): Predicate[B] =
    (b: B) => fa(f(b))
}
```

But when I do that, I have to coerce all my predicate functions to the alias like this:

```
val even: Predicate[Int] = (i: Int) => i % 2 == 0
```

Which I find annoying. So I wondered whether, rather than use the type alias, I could define predicateContra directly for a Function1 from a type variable A to Boolean, but I couldn't get it to work. Both of the following ideas give me a compiler error:

```
implicit val predicateContra = new Contravariant[Function1[_, Boolean]] {
// "Function1[_, Boolean] takes no type parameters, expected: one"

implicit def predicateContra[A] = new Contravariant[Function1[A, Boolean]] {
// "A => Boolean takes no type parameters, expected: one"
```

How can I tell the compiler that the first parameter of my Function1 should remain a "hole", while the second should be fixed to boolean? Is that even possible?
Looking at the source code for cats, I found asterisks as type parameters in a bunch of places, but that too didn't work for me.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
implicit def predicateContra = new Contravariant[Function1[*, Boolean]] {
  override def contramap[A, B](fa: Predicate[A])(f: B => A): Predicate[B] =
    (b: B) => fa(f(b))
}
```

Comment: If you want to just ignore input type for Function1 you can use * (asterisk) https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Bunyod/vz1GI9IDTfa5XSOrb3Tmvw/10

I'm not sure is it answer for your question or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [kind projector](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector), which allows you to refer to the "type hole" with an asterisk (`*`).

This enables very simple syntax for defining a type of kind `* -> *`, that is, a unary type constructor (takes a single type to produce type). For example, a type that takes some type `A` to produce the type `Map[A, Int]` can be written simply as `Map[*, Int]`.

Then your code becomes:

```
val strToBool: String => Boolean = _.contains("1")
val intToStr: Int => String = _.toString

def predicateContra = 
  new Contravariant[Function1[*, Boolean]] {
    override def contramap[A, B](fa: A => Boolean)(f: B => A): B => Boolean = 
      (b: B) => fa(f(b))
  }

predicateContra.contramap(strToBool)(intToStr)(42) // false 
predicateContra.contramap(strToBool)(intToStr)(41) // true
```

If you don't want to use extra libraries, you can do it in plain Scala in a somewhat uglier way by using a type lambda:

```
def predicateContra =
  new Contravariant[({ type lambda[A] = Function1[A, Boolean] })#lambda] {
      ...
  }
```